# Jquery alert href link

Tags: jquery, href

Can someone explain to me what is wrong here? I do not get the alert on IE or chrome. I have the Jquery in my header section and the link the body.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() 
{
$(".clicked").click(function () {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

```
<a href="#" class = "clicked" title="link">Click Link</a>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Your code above also seems to be missing a closing `})`

Comment: Yes, TY figured it out after you told me to check the console, I keep forgetting that tool is there.

Comment: So what was it? The missing `})`?

Comment: Yes the closing brackets. I am still new to Jquery, so I miss small stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

You messed up your brackets a little bit, here's a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clicked").click(function () {
        alert("clicked");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class = "clicked" title="link">Click Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be the spacing after your class attribute?

```
<a href="#" class = "clicked" title="link">Click Link</a>
```

should be

```
<a href="#" class="clicked" title="link">Click Link</a>
```

Also, your JS isn't closed properly, it should be:

```
$(function() {
    $('.clicked').on('click', function () {
        alert("clicked");
    });
});
```

Comment: No, this won't make any difference. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/36rwgL1L/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found out what I did for the other beginners out there in Jquery.

Code should be this before you insert any code into the document.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() 
{

});
```

Then after you insert code, should look like this. On my first questions I forgot }); as my closing brackets.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() 
{
    $(".clicked").click(function () {
    alert("Message to alert!");
    });
});
</script>
```

Now my href will properly show the alert.

```
<a href="#" class = "clicked" title="clicked linked">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which is called when you click the .clicked class.

Below is code on how to accomplish what you are looking to do.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".clicked").click(function () {
     alert("clicked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class = "clicked" title="link">Click Link</a>
```

Also be sure to reference jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

This version is just a cleaner way to write this code. Instead of using the document.ready function.

Comment: Don't know why you got upvoted since your answer is wrong. `$(function () {` is the shorthand equivalent of `$(document).ready( function()`

Comment: @j08691 Thank you for pointing that out. Made an edit based on your comment.